# Multidimensional Arrays and UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

How would I go about parsing through this JSON in order to populate a UITableView's label with the information in the second dimension of the array? Should I consider restructuring the JSON? This is the current structure of the JSON.

```
"1": {
    "0": {
        "title": "Unit 721",
        "price": 750,
        "priceType": 13,
        "sqftIndividual": 600
    },

    "1": {
        "title": "Unit 801",
        "price": 2330,
        "priceType": 13,
        "sqftIndividual": 900
    },

    "2": {
        "title": "Unit 1",
        "price": 9000,
        "priceType": 13,
        "sqftIndividual": 1200
    }
},
"2": {
    "parking": 1,
    "reception": 1,
    "conferenceRooms": 1,
    "kitchens": 0,
    "bathrooms": 1,
    "elevator": 1
}
```

Comment: What do you want to display in UITableViewCell? The dictionary with `title`, `price`, `priceType`, `sqftIndividual `?

Comment: exactly, id like each row to have one dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer? "It depends."

A 2-dimensional array is a very natural data structure for a sectioned table view. The outer dimension is the sections, and the inner dimension is the rows. You simply use the section number as the index into the outer array, and the row number as the index into the inner array.

If that's not the presentation you want then you need to decide what you want instead. That will inform your decision on how to map your data structure to the table view.